# It is possible to handle condition from CSS style in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

To check which input is enable, in our DOM structure(Knockout JS) there is no specific property, which says the button is enable..

Its handled by one of the CSS property, of `::before` class :

[image]

CSS: `{content: "\f013";}`

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: XXXXXX ">
 <div class=".col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 -setting-radio" data-bind="attr: " > 
  <label class="radio-position radio-inline " data-view="widgets/input/radio/view" data-active-view="true" style="">
        <input class="-widgets-input-radio-check" id="radio" type="radio" data-bind="Enable: enable, value: value, checked: checked" value="1" name="FS">
  <span class="-radio-label"></span> 
  <span class="-widgets-input-radio-text" data-bind="html: data">Global</span>
  </label>  
 </div>

 <div class=".col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 -setting-radio" data-bind="attr: " > 
  <label class="radio-position radio-inline" data-view="widgets/input/radio/view" data-active-view="true" style=""> 
    <input class="-widgets-input-radio-check" id="radio" type="radio" data-bind="Enable: enable, value: value, checked: checked" value="2" name="FS">
    <span class="-radio-label"> </span>
    <span class="-widgets-input-radio-text" data-bind="html: data">Capital</span> 
  </label>
 </div>  
</div>
```

How can we achieve it ?

Comment: could you add any example html or website where we could try it out

Comment: Its internal dev website, can not share exactly..

Comment: Let me know, if needed can share reference HTML/Style

Comment: that would be helpful

Comment: @PDHide  Added HTML

Answer (score 0):

There is a special method for this in selenium, named `value_of_css_property` The name differs on the language you use, but the idea is the same.

As I understand from your question you can use it like as in the below example:

```
assert driver.find_element_by_css_selector('css_locator').value_of_css_property("content") == "\f013"
```

HTML is not enough, you need to check which CSS properties are changed as well.
You can use it to for waits and asserts.
I use computed tab for this:
[image]

Comment: Yes, try it. But you have to define which css values are changed by yourself

Comment: Yup, we have to replace with our property.

Comment: If the answer will be helpful, accept it )

Comment: Specific css style getting active on ::before property, What can be CSS selector to locate it ?

Comment: In this case check here how to apply JavascriptExecutor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244911/selenium-webdriver-get-text-from-css-property-content-on-a-before-pseudo-ele/28265738#28265738

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230892/discussion-between-vitaliis-and-ishita-shah).

Comment: Also, check this answer. Maybe your condition changes too fast. You can control the speed of internet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66927102/trying-to-find-loading-symbols-in-angular/66927506#66927506